# Использование нестационарных рядов модели векторной авторегрессии

Tags: математика, r, статистика, анализ-данных, статический-анализ

Требуется ли, что оба входящие в VAR модель ряда были стационарными? Вроде нигде такого жесткого требования не звучит, но меня немного смущает, то что оценка проводится метод OLS, условием которого является стационарность всех рядов во избежании ложной регрессии.

Answer (score 0):

Если обе переменные стационарны, то что вы собрались предсказывать? И зачем? О стационарной модели все и так понятно -  матожидание, дисперсия, если стационарен в широком смысле - корреляция. Предсказывать-то что в таких условиях можно?

И где вы нашли, что условием применения метода наименьших квадратов является
"стационарность всех рядов". Возьмите одномерный случай - где там требуется стационарность ряда??? Стационарность остатков - да, надо. Но самого ряда??? Тогда бы вы в принципе не могли построить модель с трендом!

Comment: Я вот честно не специалист, но вроде как нестационарность рядов создает ложную регрессию (но это только по литературе, не знаю, как на практике). Допустим первая попавшаяся цитата "Существует феномен, который заключается в том, что если оценить регрессию одного нестационарного ряда на другие нестационарные ряды, 
то оценки OLS-коэффициентов будут часто значимы, даже когда фактически  зависимости между рядами нет" (Скроботов А.А., Турунцева М.Ю
Тестирование гипотезы о наличии единичного корня 
для независимых панелей).  Строить регрессию на сырых данных это вроде университетский подход.

Comment: И как-то странно, var то, конечно, применяется, для прогнозирования, но это не было целью исследования (тогда бы использовалась автоматическая sarima).

Comment: И кажется поняла , что Вас смутило, речь идет о ts -рядах , то есть стационарных рядах относительно детерминированного тренда.

Comment: "если оценить регрессию одного нестационарного ряда на другие .., то оценки OLS-коэффициентов будут часто значимы, даже когда фактически зависимости между рядами нет". Известный феномен. Называется ложная регрессия.  На уровне формальных методов не обнаруживается никак.  Что значит "регрессия на сырых данных это вроде университетский подход" - не очень вас понял. Если под "приготовлением" данных вы подразумеваете выделение тренда и случайной компоненты - то да. Но случайные компоненты на то и случайные, что они между собой должны остаться некоррелированными, а модели строим только для трендов.

Answer (score 0):

Желательно, чтоб все ряды были стационарными, если они не коинтегрированные.
According to Chris Brooks (2014), in his book Introductory Econometrics for Finance, "If one wishes to use hypothesis tests, either singly or jointly, to examine the statistical significance of the coefficients, then it is essential that all of the components in the VAR are stationary."
Источник ответа: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_it_necessary_to_ensure_stationarity_of_all_time_series_variables_when_you_run_a_Vector_Autoregressive_VAR_Model
Информация об учебнике: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/introductory-econometrics-for-finance/75E9C608EA95A3AD87FB3BC683B9EBBF

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю, что поздно, но да, в целом рекомендуется делать ряды стационарными для модели VAR. Это часто упоминается в разных статьях и также в учебниках, например [здесь](https://otexts.com/fpp2/VAR.html) в 11.2 главе. Полагаю, есть непосредственно теоретические (математические) обоснования для этого решения, но тогда нужно вникать в более специализированную литературу

Comment: По ссылке, которую вы привели, написано: "If the series are stationary, we forecast them ..... If the series are non-stationary, we take differences of the data in order to make them stationary......" Т.е., данные могут быть как стационарными так и нестационарными. Но! Если данные стационарные, то все что можно предсказать-это распределение вашей случайной величины. А для нестационарного ряда вы предсказываете не само значение, а будущие разности. Есть и другие методы предсказания нестационарных рядов, не требующие взятия разностей. И да, для такого предсказания надо вникать в спецлитературу.

Comment: В соответствии с тем, что написано в том учебнике, ряды действительно могут быть стационарным или нестационарными изначально. И если нестационарны, предлагается использовать разности, чтобы сделать их стационарными (за исключением случаев с коинтеграцией), и далее анализировать. Это то, что я и имел ввиду: что для использования VAR рекомендуется брать стационарные ряды; они могут быть изначально нестационарны, и тогда, в соответствии с той ссылкой (и некоторыми другими), их нужно сделать стационарными. Касательно других методов, где стационарность необязательна - да, их я тоже учу по чуть-чуть

Comment: Возможно, здесь просто языковая путаница, например взятие разности нестационарного временного ряда и называется часто как "сделать ряд стационарным", ну если оно действительно поможет в соответствии с разными тестами. Полагаю, что изначально про это и спрашивалось

Comment: Замечу, чтобы сделать ряд стационарным существует много, очень много методов.Начиная с элементарных регрессионных методов выделения трендовой компоненты, даже элементарного скользящего среднего.На все это может накладываться сепарация сезонной составляющей.В более сложных моделях типа Хольта-Уинтерса выделение составляющей положения встроено в саму модель. В итоге- получите (или нет- и тогда надо применять более сложные методы) стационарный ряд. А дальше, про стационарный ряд- то что я сказал: матожидание, дисперсия, в лучшем случае - функция распределения.Вот и все 
инструменты предсказания.

Comment: Я лишь дал тот ответ, который указывается во многих учебниках по прогнозированию, и полагаю, что он уместен в соответствии с изначальным вопросом. Возможно, просто присутствовало недопонимание, а касательно всего остального, методов, других моделей - я согласен, но речи изначально не шло

Comment: Некоторые модели требуют стационарности и лучше работают, когда она есть, и это рекомендуется в случае с VAR. Почему VAR именно такая модель, для которой рекомендуют стационарность, я не знаю

Comment: ну, стационарный ряд, значить стационарный. Значит матодижание, дисперсия и автокорреляция не изменяются во времени (!!). Что предсказывать-то будем? Конкретное, точечное значение в некоторой пусть даже ближайшей) точке "будущего"? Серйозно?

Comment: Если ты не согласен с тем, что пишут ученые в своих учебниках, я ничем не помогу, я учусь по ним. Здесь я дал ответ, который в большинстве случаев признается правильным, не более того. Я могу сослаться ещё на ряд источников, если это будет необходимо

Comment: Если ВЫ учите, то дайте ответ на вопрос -  что-же будем предсказывать в случае стационарности? Он действительно правильный, и он действительно приводится в любом учебнике. Только учебники надо читать думая. И быть уверенным, что вы правильно понимаете, что там написано.  А означает это именно то, что я написал в самом первом ответе. Приведение ряда к стационарному виду - это промежуточный этап исследования, а не самоцель. Получив предсказания от такого ряда, ими надо воспользоваться  с умом, что-бы получить окончательный ответ на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: Вопрос звучал так:"Требуется ли, что оба входящие в VAR модель ряда были стационарными?". Я дал правильный ответ, и с тобой не спорил. Обсуждать что-то за пределами исходного вопроса я не был намерен с самого начала, считаю это нерелевантным. И я не на уроке, чтобы отчитываться